# Checking if user is at the bottom of the page doesn't work on Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, web, mobile

I have this pagination system where when the window is scrolled it checks if it's scrolled to the bottom and if so it does something.

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
       if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
          console.log('bottom');
       }
    });
```

This works perfectly on desktop but on Android Chrome it doesn't. I was thinking maybe it's the way chrome calculates these jQuery methods on Android. is there a way I can fix that or will this calculation not work for mobile?

**UPDATE:** I just checked on Apple's Safari and it worked there but on multiple android devices it doesn't.

Comment: I've already searched and tried all the said solutions and none of them worked!

Comment: Tried it, seems to work on my phone. Could be some old JS code which are cached on your phone? Try clear the cache if you haven't already.

Comment: No I cleared my cache everytime I tried a new approach and I don't seem to find the issue

Comment: Could this work better in the IF statement: (($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) >= document.documentElement.scrollHeight) ? Seems like some browsers doesn't support document.height.

Comment: I realized that on mobile it doesn't reach the end so the if statement needs to be ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 100)